# Find multiple substrings within a string with unknown ending

Tags: php, string

We have content of a page which has multiple instances of  `get_template_part` in them. We want to grab them in an array do `eval` on them so we could include those template parts as well.

The problem is we know the beginning `"get_template_part"` and the ending `"');"` but the ending is the same for a lot of similar instances we don't want to grab.

How do we grab only the ending of `get_template_part` and disclude all others

Example of a String we want to include: `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/breadcrumbs' ); ?>`

I tried the following function which accepts a haystack and 2 needles and returns the matching string but then again the second needle is no way exclusive to the first needle

```
function get_substring_part($haystack, $needle, $needle2, $find) {

$lastPos_one = 0;
$lastPos_two = 0;
$positions_one = array();
$positions_two = array();

while (($lastPos_one = strpos($haystack, $needle, $lastPos_one))!== false) {
    $positions_one[] = $lastPos_one;
    $lastPos_one = $lastPos_one + strlen($needle);
}
foreach ($positions_one as $value_start) {
    $return[]['start'] =  $value_start;
}

while (($lastPos_two = strpos($haystack, $needle2, $lastPos_two))!== false) {
    $positions_two[] = $lastPos_two;
    $lastPos_two = $lastPos_two + strlen($needle2);
}
foreach ($positions_two as $value_end) {
    $return[]['end'] =  $value_end;
}

$counter = 0;
foreach ($return as $positions) {
    $string['start'] = $positions['start'];
    $string['end'] = $positions['end'];
    $var = substr($haystack, $positions['start'], $positions['end']);


    if (strpos($var, $find) !== false) {
        $string['string'] = substr($haystack, $positions['start'], $positions['end']);
    }
    $counter++;
}

return $string;
}
```

Im using this function with the following attributes:

```
get_substring_part($content, 'get_template_part', ');', 'get_template_part')
```

Comment: Do you have some examples? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add a sample string with what you are trying to grab and what to exclude

Comment: Can you show all the instances of `get_template_part` at once and show the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full matches will be in `$matches[0]` and what is in between the `' '` will be in `$matches[1]`.  You can move the `( )` to get more or less and add the `<?php` if you need it:

```
preg_match_all("/get_template_part\s*\(\s*'(.+?)'\s*\);?/", $template, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

- Match `get_template_part` then `\s*` space 0 or more
- Then `(` then `\s*` space 0 or more
- Then `'` then `(.+?)` capture `.` characters `+?` 1 or more lazy
- Then `'` then `\s*` space 0 or more then `)` then `;` optional `?`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Let me debug this more and ill mark this as correct

Comment: Let's hope you won't have things such as `get_template_part(generate_part())`, or `get_template_part('look/someone/put/brackets()')`

Comment: All working fine expect these: `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/frontpage/section', 'popular' ) ?>` `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/frontpage/section', 'videos' ) ?>`

Comment: @Cid: Actually the parentheses don't cause a problem.  Maybe the absence of quotes `'` but they showed them in the question.

Comment: a PHP parser would maybe suits rather this need rather than RegEx

Comment: @FahadSohail:  Try a `?` after the `;`.